# Shell copying file with biggest size to another folder

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Linux shell and I found a way to get the name of the file I want:

```
ls *.*g -S| grep -v ^d | head -1
```

I am going to be repeating this for a number of file. I am trying to copy this file to another directory (cp command?). But the below code is failing.

I am trying this, but its not working:

```
cp ls -S| grep -v ^d | head -1 ../directory
```

Also, I was wondering how to loop through directorys that are in a particular directory.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cp $(ls *.*g -S| grep -v ^d | head -1) ../directory
```

Comment: note that you won't be able to grep for ^d, since `ls` is used without `-l`

Comment: @kurumi your comment seems more appropriate aimed at the OP. Unfortunately he does not give us the file names he is looking for but he says that pipeline works so I have no choice but to believe him. The main point of this answer regardless of his implementation is **command substitution** via `$()`

Answer (score 0):

```
cp "$(find . -type f -name "*.*" -printf "%f:%s\n" | sort -t":" -k2 -n | awk -F":" 'END{print $1}')" ../directory
```

Use quotes in case there are white spaces in your file. add `-maxdepth 1` if you don't want to recurse subdirectories